# Can't access member variables or methods from reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Small confusion on how references work.
If I have a reference, can I access the member methods and variables? Shouldn't it be the same with a pointer? Can I transform the reference into a pointer?

Issue is in accessing elements from returning object of `getName()` further

```
template <typename T>
bool BSTree<T>::insert(BSTNode<T>* currentnode, T* data) {
    std::string value = data -> getName();
    std::string current = currentnode -> getData() -> getName(); 
    return false;
}
```

The error is:
"base operand of `->` has non-pointer type `Object`"

If I try to use the `getName()` method that is part of the object `getData()` is returning (via a reference) then why doesn't it work just like the previous line? On my previous program, returning the object via a method similar to `getData()` worked just fine.

Comment: Need more context. Also please post text as text not as a picture of text.

Comment: Please cut'n'paste code rather than images

Comment: Please let us know what the error is (red squiggly underline). Or the output from the compiler related to this line. PS stack overflow has code highlighting and formatting, use that instead of an image of the code.

Comment: paste your whole code.

Comment: `T` is an unspecified type and `data` points to an instance of that _unspecified_. How does the compiler determine whether it implements `getName()` or `getData()` in accessible scope?

Comment: I specified it by adding: "template class BSTree<Object>;" to the bottom of the .template

Comment: @Ky6000 You're not showing that in your question. You're not showing declaration of `getName()` or `getData()`. You haven't bothered to show important details relevant to your problem. All that does is delay you getting an answer. The most efficient way to get help is to post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getData()` is returning a reference, then you would use:

```
std::string current = currentnode->getData().getName();
```

In general, `->` dereferences a pointer, you don't use it with references.

Answer (score 1):

> "If I try to use the getName() method that is part of the object getData is returning (via a reference)"...

We cannot see how `getData` is declared but chances are that it returns a reference (not a pointer) hence you should use `.` not `->`